# Regex: Match optional characters but if present match that first

Tags: regex, perl

I have to match

```
Salutation(optional) FirstName LastName
```

My regex is:

```
^(([mMrRsSdDlLtTcCoO]{2,4})\.?\s+)?([a-zA-Z,.'-]{2,}\s+)([a-zA-Z,.'-]{2,})$
```

The problem with my regex is it works fine with

*Mrs. Pamela Anderson* or *Pamela Anderson*

as well on *Miss Pamela* (wrong case).

Comment: Why are you not using the `|` separator?

Comment: You are missing at least two `(` at the beginning...

Comment: What about the following valid case: Mrs. Miss Pamela (saying that her first name is "Miss")? Are you certain that there isn't any "Salutation" that could be a first name as well?

Comment: I would just split the string at the space character.

Comment: Food for thought: The title `Prof. Dr.` contains a space. Some forms of address don't contain personal names e.g. `Her Majesty the Queen`. Some names may contain non-ASCII characters, e.g. Arabic names → you may want to use unicode semantics, and the `\w` charclass. Some names have middle names (e.g. `Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart`) which may be considered part of the first name. Some cultures (China) place the surname first, followed by given names. Consider single-char names and nobility indicators. [→ WP article on naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_name#Naming_convention)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is matching `Miss` as FirstName and `Pamela` as Last name

your regex should be

```
^(?!(Mr|Miss|..)[.]?\s+[a-zA-Z,.'-]+$)[a-zA-Z,.'-]+[.]?(\s+[a-zA-Z,.'-]){1,2}$
 -------------------------------------
         |
         |->don't match further if it has Salutation and firstname or lastname
```

---

As a side note,don't use `[mMrRsSdDlLtTcCoO]{2,4}` there can be many permutations of valid names like coco(my friends name),Rod

Specify it explicitly using `|` like `(Mr|Mrs|Miss|Dr)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?:^[mMrRsSdDlLtTcCoO]{2,4}\.?\s+?)?([\w,.'-]{2,})\s+([\w,.'-]{2,})
```